# How to use redis lock to prevent asynchronous Job in Python

Tags: python, redis, odoo-12

Currently I am using Redis to perform the QueueJob(Priority Queue) in Python code(Odoo) and I meet the asynchronous problem (There will have some jobs doing the same task - update/delete in the same record at the same time).

As I read from Redis documentation that I need to implement a LOCK to prevent the the asynchronous problem. However, I don't why the lock does not run as I expect.

Below is my code:

```
import redis
import redis_lock #(python-redis-lock lib)

class PriorityQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, queue_name):
        ...
        self.redis = redis.StrictRedis(...)
        self.redis_lock = redis_lock.Lock(self.redis, queue_name)


    def first(self):
        if self.redis_lock.acquire(blocking=False):
            print("Perform task")
            job = self.redis.zrevrange(self.queue_name, 0, 0)[0]
            job_data = json.loads(job.decode("utf-8"))
            return ChannelJob(job_data)
        else:
            print("Lock is used by other job")

    def pop(self):
        job = self.redis.zpopmax(self.queue_name, count=1)
        job_data = json.loads(job.decode("utf-8"))
        return ChannelJob(job_data)
```

The redis_lock.acquire() is always return False, Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**You forget to release the lock.**

> The redis_lock.acquire() is always return False

Actually thats not true. For the first time at least a single job acquire the lock. **And as you forget to release the lock the lock persists**. And any subsequent request failed. To solve this problem you need to release the locks `self.redis_lock.release()`. Here is an example:

```
def first(self):
        if self.redis_lock.acquire(blocking=False):
            print("Perform task")
            job = self.redis.zrevrange(self.queue_name, 0, 0)[0]
            job_data = json.loads(job.decode("utf-8"))

            // do the job ; you can also release the lock here.
            job_result = ChannelJob(job_data)
            // release the lock, so other can acquire it.
            self.redis_lock.release()
            return job_result 
        else:
            print("Lock is used by other job")
```

To learn more about the locks: [Please visit this links](https://pypi.org/project/python-redis-lock/)

Comment: Also, if there is no timeout defined for the lock, manually find that redis key and delete it.